# JSON lib to handle circular references and abstract classes?

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'm looking for a json (de)serialization library that can

- serialize collections like List() and nested lists
- can compete with circular references, as often occur in hibernate mappings
- can handle lists with objects implementing a abstract class

I tried:

- Gson (has neither abstract class nor circular dep support. There are some hack extra classes, but they don't work well)
- flexjson (has problems with deep lists)

Is there anything out that can handle all of this by not having to apply "hacky" things?

Comment: Did you try JSON-lib? http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Circular dependencies will always lead into "hacky things".It sounds, as if would be a good idea to take a step back and create DTOs without circles.

Comment: Genson lib handles 1 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found JACKSON to be very intuitive and easy configurable for all my needs.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using YAML instead of JSON is an option? YAML is a superset of JSON and has built-in support for circular references and advanced data types.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://x-stream.github.io/ (fast and feature rich) or http://json-lib.sourceforge.net (as @Cleber Alberto suggested) with customized circular references handling.

Comment: first link is bad. asks for authentication.